# Java unknown exception

Tags: java, sql

I have this method in my AbstractServer:

```
  synchronized protected void clientException(
    ConnectionToClient client, Throwable exception) {
        try
        {
          client.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
  }
```

It's purpose is to catch all uncatched exceptions from the client and terminate their connection to server. Here is the close method:

```
  final public void close() throws IOException
  {
    readyToStop = true; // Set the flag that tells the thread to stop

    try
    {
      closeAll();
    }
    finally
    {
      server.clientDisconnected(this);
    }
  }
```

Ii have the following method on my server:

```
public ArrayList<String> getMemberdetails (ArrayList<String> string)
{
    ArrayList<String> ref = new ArrayList<String>();
    try 
    {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String s = new String ("SELECT * FROM readercard mc, sysuser s WHERE s.userID=mc.userID AND mc.userID='"+ string.get(1) +"'");
        System.out.println(s);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM readercard mc, sysuser s WHERE s.userID=mc.userID AND mc.userID='"+ string.get(1) +"'");
        if(rs.next())
        {
            ref.add(rs.getString("userFirstName"));
            ref.add(rs.getString("userLastName"));
            ref.add(rs.getString("email"));
            ref.add(rs.getString("status"));
            ref.add(rs.getString("userPhone"));             
        }
        if (!rs.first())
            ref.add(null);
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException  e) {e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();} 

    return ref;
}
```

This method lunches every time a client starts a connection and it works when called the first time.

The problem occurs when I call this method from another method on server. At the line: `stmt = conn.createStatement();` it is not working. The client application gets stuck and in the server log I see that the server called the close method for the client (which means that exception happened).

If I continue debugging with that line  server immediately shows this page:
[image]

First I have no idea what exception that might be as I said the method `getMemberdetails` works just fine on the first call (which is every time a client signs in the application). Second, if `stmt = conn.createStatement();` throws a `SQLException` exception why doesn't it get caught in the catch statement?

Comment: There's something I don't understand about clientException. Who calls it and when? How is it bound to the "unhandled exception" event?

Comment: its a hook method called each time an exception is thrown in a
ConnectionToClient thread.

Comment: Whould you mind removing the hook for a while, and trying again? Let the exceptions just blow up the thread. Less stuff around, more possibility to find your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, you provide us a very scattered code; I mean a lot of parts, which are not somehow linked with each other. The problem I noticed in this answer was a single possible solution, which could be extracted from your question now. I suggest you remove screenshot of a page, because it has no sense at all.

Comment: Did you check if `conn` is null while you were debugging? Also you could put a breakpoint in your `clientException` method to see if it is called, and if so what the throwable passed in is.

Comment: conn is not null it's being initialized in server constractor

Comment: try immediately surrounding `stmt = conn.createStatement();` with a try catch block.. that might help

Comment: @jschoen yet you didn't fix the title?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar yes, I have a bad habit of forgetting to check titles for typos also. Sorry about that.

Comment: When you step through `getMemberdetails` where does the control go when you step over `stmt = conn.createStatement();`?

Comment: @Miserable Variable  it does to the "Class file editor" print screen is above. if i understood it correctly it appears when there is a problem with the SQL java connector (JAR file) yet.. if that is the case.. how did it work on the first time?

Comment: you should be able to attach `mysql` source to get a better idea. What is the stack trace at that time?

Comment: I don't know if `Connection` is `thread-safe`. Is `getMemberdetails` called from multiple threads?

Comment: i printed the stuck trace in the exceptions.. since for some reason i dont catch the exception i cant print the trace.... the connector is attached to the project.. all other methods works very well!

Comment: getMemberdetails called for each thread at start. later it might be called again but it's not compulsory. the problem is when it's called again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22993/discussion-between-miserable-variable-and-ronn-jack)

Comment: try making it `synchronized`